# How to update dynamic ng-values in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to update the `ng-values` of a dropdown based on a condition.

This is the html code:

```
<dropdown ng-model="vm.current.scheduleCompletedWithinType" ng-values="vm.completedWithinTypeValuesFiltered"
              ng-change="vm.update()" ng-if="main.user.can.writeDefinitions"></dropdown>
```

The `scheduleCompletedWithinType` variable is created like this:

```
vm.completedWithinTypeValues = scheduleService.getFrequencyTypes()
vm.completedWithinTypeValuesFiltered = Array.from(vm.completedWithinTypeValues)
vm.completedWithinTypeValuesFiltered.splice(0, 1)
```

Where I have a full list of schedule times on `completedWithinTypeValues` variable and I have the filtered one on `completedWithinTypeValuesFiltered`. When an input changes, I do this:

```
function resetCompletedWithinValues(allowTimeDue) {
    if (allowTimeDue) {
      vm.completedWithinTypeValuesFiltered = vm.completedWithinTypeValues
    } else {
      vm.completedWithinTypeValuesFiltered = Array.from(vm.completedWithinTypeValues)
      vm.completedWithinTypeValuesFiltered.splice(0, 1)
    }
}
```

So the `completedWithinTypeValuesFiltered` is updated. But I don't see that value on my ng-values dropdown. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by doing:

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(vm.completedWithinTypeValuesFiltered, vm.completedWithinTypeValues)
```